# Count columns on a conditional basis and perform multiplication in one VIEW MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of twitter data in MYSQL where the columns is_retweet, is_reply is made of binary values where 1=yes, 0=no. if a user retweeted multiple times in a day, there would then be multiple rows of ones in the retweet coulmn for that user on that day.

```
account_id,    datetime,        user_screenname, is_retweet, is_reply,followers_count
'9',      '2008-06-11 20:06:35','Access2',        '1',         '0',     '811' 
'9',      '2008-06-11 23:06:35','Access2',        '1',         '1',     '812' 
'9',      '2008-06-12 20:01:21','Access2',        '0',         '1',     '813' 
'7',      '2008-06-11 17:01:00','actingparty',    '1',         '1',     '2000'
```

I rearrange my sql output to a table below which tells me: for a username on any day, what is the total number of retweets, replies and highest follower count.

```
account_id,    date,        user_screenname, sum_retweet, sum_reply, followers_count
'9',         '2008-06-11',        'Access2',        '2',         '0',     '812' 
'9',         '2008-06-12',        'Access2',        '0',         '1',     '813'
```

Here is my sql code:

```
CREATE VIEW `tweet_sum` AS
    select 
        `tweets`.`account_id` AS `account_id`,
        `tweets`.`user_screenname` AS `user_screenname`,
        CAST(`tweets`.`datetime` as date) AS `period`,
        MAX(`tweets`.`followers_count`) AS `followers_count`,
        SUM(`tweets`.`is_reply`) AS `sum_reply`,
        SUM(`tweets`.`is_retweet`) AS `sum_retweet`,

    from
        `tweets`
    group by cast(`tweets`.`datetime` as date), tweets.username
```

---

**Ultimately, I want to have one more column Reach (which is equal to followers_count times the number of columns(is_retweet, is_reply) that is greater than zero.)
For example, in the output table below, the sum_retweet and sum_reply columns are both greater than zero for 2008-06-11 so i will need to take followers_count*2=1624 for the reach column.**

How can i structure my sql code to do that?

```
account_id,    date,        user_screenname, sum_retweet, sum_reply, followers_count, **Reach** 
'9',         '2008-06-11',        'Access2',        '2',         '1',     '812',      '1624'
'9',         '2008-06-12',        'Access2',        '0',         '1',     '813',       '813'
```

I thought of doing it this way:

```
1.create a new view
2.count the number of columns that have values >0 
3.then take that number multiply by followers count for that day
```

And the code for that below:

```
CREATE VIEW tweet_reach AS
SELECT 
COUNT(t.sum_reply,t.sum_retweet,t.sun_mention,t.sum_direct,t.sum_mytweet)*t.followers_count AS Reach
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name='tweet_sum' t AND
   t.sum_reply>0 OR
   t.sum_retweet>0 OR
   t.sun_mention>0 OR
   t.sum_direct>0 OR
    t.sum_mytweet>0;
```

This code is wrong but hoping to do something like this. Is it possible?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily by adding a column in your existing view:

```
CREATE VIEW `tweet_sum` AS
    select `tweets`.`account_id` AS `account_id`,
           `tweets`.`user_screenname` AS `user_screenname`,
           CAST(`tweets`.`datetime` as date) AS `period`,
           MAX(`tweets`.`followers_count`) AS `followers_count`,
           SUM(`tweets`.`is_reply`) AS `sum_reply`,
           SUM(`tweets`.`is_retweet`) AS `sum_retweet`,
           MAX(`tweets`.`followers_count`) * ((SUM(`tweets`.`is_reply`) > 0) + (SUM(`tweets`.`is_retweet`) > 0)) as reach
    from `tweets`
    group by cast(`tweets`.`datetime` as date), tweets.username;
```

MySQL treats a boolean expression such as `x = y` as the integer `1` when true and `0` when false.  So, you can just add them together for your multiplication factor.

Comment: if instead of just checking to see if the column say 'is_reply' is greater than 0 then let value =1, what if i am interested in the value of the is_reply (for example the value is 3) and i want  MAX(`tweets`.`followers_count`) * 3 given the value is >0?

Comment: @jenn . . . That might best be asked as another question.